# Confusion matrix order in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

I have 6 classes and I used tf-slim in Tensorflow to obtained the confusion matrix such as

```
[[41  2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1 11  4  1  0  0]
 [ 0  1  12  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 22  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  7  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0 20]]
```

My question is that what is confusion matrix order of the above table? Is it right if I said that the columns represent the prediction label, while the rows represent the true label? Some reference said on opposite side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use [`tf.confusion_matrix(labels,predictions)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix)?

If so, the columns represent the predicton labels, whereas the rows represent the real labels.

Comment: Thanks. So for example of class 1 (index from 0 to n-1). It correctly predict 11 and false to class is 1 +4 + 1=6. Am I right?

Comment: For class1, you have 11 true positives, 3 false positives (i.e. you predicted class 1 which is not true) and 6 false negatives (i.e. you didn't predict class 1, although that would've been correct).

Answer (score 1):

The usual representation is

```
    PREDICTED
 [[41  2  0  0  0  0]
T [ 1 11  4  1  0  0]
R [ 0  1  12 0  0  0]
U [ 0  0  0 22  1  0]
E [ 0  0  0  0  7  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0 20]]
```

As pointed out by M. Rath (+1), this is also what Tensorflow does. This means for 41 samples you correctly predicted class 0. For 2 samples, you predicted class 1, but it actually was class 0.

Please note that you can also manipulate the order for visualizations. So instead of

```
class 0, class 1, class 2
```

you could have (for both, prediction and true value) the order

```
class 0, class 2, class 1
```

This contains the same information, but a visualization might convey a different story. See my masters thesis [Analysis and Optimization of
Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=48) page 48 (Confusion Matrix Ordering), especially figure 5.12 and 5.13.

An implementation can be found in the tool [`clana`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/clana)